# What to do with a VMP video file

Tags: video

I recieved a VMP video file to convert to avi or mpeg or something. I searched the web but I cannot find any association with this file.

Can anyone help? Which program does this file come from?
What can I do with it?

Comment: Seems to be a video from a Sony/Vaio product. Can't find anything about it on the web.

Comment: I can't find any information on anything using that file extension.  Is it small enough that you might be able to post the file or atleast post the first few hundred characters if you open it in a hex or text editor?  That might be helpful for identifying if it is some standard format that has had the extension altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a video from a Sony/Vaio product having a vmp extension.  I don't know of any third party converters, however you should be able to export the video file from your Vaio/Sony product itself.  It'll automatically create an mpeg video file for you.

Comment: Good lead on the Vaio products.  Are you sure there are no third party tools out there that can access it?  My quick search didn't show any reliable links, but I didn't get a chance to dig in to any of the more questionable ones looking for an answer.